# Extracting patterns from files

Tags: bash, zsh

I am trying to extract patterns from cat ing a file in a bash script.
I need to extract 10 and 80 line by line. How do I do this?

```
Total Branch Predictor Mispredictions: 10
Total Branch Predictor OK predictions: 80
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat > data
Total Branch Predictor Mispredictions: 10
Total Branch Predictor OK predictions: 80
$ cat data | awk '{print $NF}'
10
80
$ cat data | awk '{printf "%s ",$NF}'
10 80 $ awk '{printf "%s ",$NF}' < data
10 80 $
```

`awk` not only knows `$1`, `$2` etc. to address the *n*-th column, but also `$NF` to address the last column (in this case, `10` and `80`). The second command utilises `printf` rather than `print` to spit out everything in one line (observe the missing newline at the end). The third command avoids using `cat`.

There is also a solution involving `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^[^:]*: \([0-9]*\)/\1 /' < data
10
80
```

And one only involving `bash`:

```
$ while read line; do printf "%s " "${line##*: }"; done < data; echo
10 80 
$
```

which reads the file line by line, mangles the `line` variable by deleting the largest matching pattern from the left (in this case: everything up to `:`) and passing it to `printf`, which then proceeds to format it. I added `echo` at the end to get a final newline :)

Comment: I think the OP meant that he wants to see the correlating performance data in one line, like `10 80` (though it's hard to guide somebody when he doesn't specify, where he wants to get)

Comment: in this case, use `cat data | awk '{printf "%s ",$NF}'`.

Comment: and, to avoid the useless use of cat, try `$ awk '{printf "%s ",$NF}' < data` (although the OP explicitly said _cat ing_).

Comment: I think you should add these bits to the answer, it will be useful for the future [SU] dweller...